# dockerized HAProxy+Keepalived for HA

Tags: docker, haproxy, high-availability

I have one host with HAProxy running as docker container using docker compose . I want to scale out our HAProxy horizontally to make it highly available across multiple hosts.

I read few tutorials with keepalived but that is done on the host & with being HAProxy server installed as a host & not in docker container .

Is it possible to deploy highly available HAProxy in a dockerized way ?

(I understand that i have a virtualized setup)

Comment: Any success on this project?

Comment: No.  I ended up using single simple  Haproxy setup.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a HAProxy and a Keepalived in a container with main process. Docker provide `--privileged` param, so Keepalived can get the VIP(Virtual IP) through this way in a container.

About how to run multiple processes in a container, you can refer to docs: [multi-service-container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

After you started `Haproxy & Keepalived` more than to nodes, VIP can drift between these nodes. With same haproxy.cfg, you can access HAProxy service with VIP. So that you can get the High-Avaliable HAProxy service.

About how to run `HAProxy & Keepalived` in a container, there is an image you can try it: [docker haproxy-keepalived](https://hub.docker.com/r/pelin/haproxy-keepalived/)